# Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook

I recently got an fb social plugin. In particular, the "Like" button for my website. Everything works okay it's just that when I click on the button, it reads "You like:http://www.branchout.com/index.php?id=3"

I don't want it to say what URL i like. I want it to say the content of what I'm liking (in this case, it's a quote).

One more thing, my domain name is "thebranchout.com", not "branchout.com"

and thoughts, guys?

The head of the code is this:

```
<head>
<title><?php echo $last; ?>) <?php echo $first; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Sharing stuff, quotes, politicians, athletes" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Sharing stuff, quotes, politicians, athletes" />
<meta property="og:title" content="(<?php echo $last; ?>) <?php echo $first; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="song" />
<meta property="og:type" content="cause"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.thebranchout.com/index.php?id=<?php echo $jeeves; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The BranchOut"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="(<?php echo $last; ?>) <?php echo $first; ?>"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-wampler.css" media="" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery.jqEasyCharCounter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#slide").hide();

    $('.button').click(function checkPass(){
        $("#slide").slideDown(); 
    });

    $('textarea#limit').jqEasyCounter({
        'maxChars': 99,
        'maxCharsWarning': 95,
        'msgFontSize': '14px',
        'msgFontColor': 'black',
        'msgFontFamily': 'Verdana',
        'msgTextAlign': 'left',
        'msgWarningColor': 'red',
        'msgAppendMethod': 'insertBefore'               
    });
});
</script>
```

The iframe is this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=thebranchout.com/index.php?id=<?php echo $jeeves; ?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Code would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Feed your page to [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and it will tell you how facebook grabs information about your page.

Comment: Not only that, but the URL Linter will update Facebook's cache of your metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put open graph tags in your page  which Facebook uses to produce a title, image, and description on news feeds, and also a title to replace the URL that you're seeing.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 0):

I think facebook parses the page for info to use. Make sure the page at that URL has a valid title set in the header. I am not sure what they pull to use for descritpion etc. though.